# How to refresh dataTable in ReactJS after the modal save button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

On my second week of learning React.

I need some help on how to refresh the dataTable in reactJs when I clicked the save button from the modal.

Here is my structure.

I have a parameterMaintenance.jsx below which imports the DataTable Component

ParameterMaintenance.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { ParameterDatable } from '../../components/ParameterDatatable'

export const ParameterMaintenance = () => {

  return (
    <div className='container mt-5'>
    <div></div>
    <ParameterDatatable/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and then, I have a ParameterDataTable.jsx file that holds the dataTable.
notice that here, I called the AddParameter.jsx from the
DataTable actions property like this `actions={<AddParameter/>}`
to add a button that displays the modal form that handles the Saving of a new Parameter.

ParameterDatatable.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component'; 
import DataTableExtensions from 'react-data-table-component-extensions';
import 'react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AddParameter } from './AddParameter';

export const ParameterDatatable= () => {

    const [parameters, setParameters] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadParameters();
    }, []);

    
    const loadParameters = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/parameters");
        setParameters(result.data);
    };
    
    const deleteParam = async (id) => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/parameter/${id}`);
        loadParameters();
    };

    const column = [
        {
          name: "Param Name",
          selector: (row) => row.param_name,
          width: "180px" ,
          sortable: true,
          alignItems: 'center',
          display: 'flex',
        },
        {
          name: "Sequence Number",
          selector: (row) => row.param_sequence_number,
          width: "150px" ,
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: "Parameter Value",
            selector: (row) => row.param_value,
            width: "150px" ,
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: "",
            width: "110px" ,
            cell: row =>  
            <div className="App">
            <div className="openbtn text-center">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#myModal"
                
              >
                Delete
              </button>

              <div className="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                  <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                      <h5 className="modal-title">Danger</h5>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn-close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"
                      ></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                      <p>Do you want to remove this record premanently?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      >
                        Close
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => deleteParam(row.param_id)}
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                        Yes
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                ,
        },
        {
            name: "",
            width: "110px" ,
            cell: row =>  
                    <button
                    className="btn btn-primary mx-2"
                    onClick={() => deleteParam(row.param_id)}>
                      Edit
                </button>,
        },
      ]   
   
  return (
    <div className="datatable">
    <DataTableExtensions
    
    columns={column}
    data={parameters}
    print={false}
    export={false}
  >
    <DataTable 
        title="Parameters"
        columns={column} 
        data={parameters} 
        pagination
        fixedHeader
        fixedHeaderScrollHeight="450px"
        highlightOnHover
        actions={<AddParameter/>}
        
      subHeader

    />
    </DataTableExtensions>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: create New]

And below is my AddParameter.jsx which is the modal form for saving new parameter

AddParameter.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const AddParameter = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [parameter, setParameter] = useState({
        param_name: "",
        param_sequence_number: "",
        param_value: "",
    });

    const {param_name, param_sequence_number, param_value} = parameter;

    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        setParameter({ ...parameter, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };   

      const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitting");
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/parameter", parameter);
        navigate('admin/parameter1');

      };   

  return (
    <div>
    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Create New</button>
    <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Parameter</h5>
          <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label for="recipient-name" className="col-form-label">Parameter Name</label>
              <input type={"text"} className="form-control" placeholder="Param Name" name="param_name" value={param_name}
               onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" className="col-form-label">Sequence Number</label>
              <input type={"text"} className="form-control" placeholder="Sequence Number" name="param_sequence_number" value={param_sequence_number}
               onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" className="col-form-label">Parameter Value</label>
              <input type={"text"} className="form-control" placeholder="Value" name="param_value" value={param_value}
               onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save Parameter</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

[image: AddParameterModal]

what I wanted to do is when I clicked the Save button, it will close the modal and refresh the DataTable, or call the loadParameters function which gets data from API in ParameterDataTable.jsx

Tried to use the navigate in reactjs to try to reload the page but the address will just add to the current address like this.
[image: Navigate]

Comment: Why don't you add a prop with loadParameters function to AddParameter, pass it from DataTable and call it on click save?

Comment: able to study props sir, thanks for it, it's already working, right now my only problem is after saving/creating a new record, when i click the create new button, the data that was save previosly is already in the text box and not cleared

Comment: That is a different issue, in that case you should reset the state after closing the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one possible approach:

Pass `loadParameter` function as a prop of `AddParameter` component and call it when sending the form or when clicking the button.

```
export const AddParameter = (props) => {

  ....

      const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitting");
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/parameter", parameter);
        props.loadParameter()

      };  
  ...// or call it onClick
```

Then pass it from the parent component

```
 <DataTable 
        title="Parameters"
        columns={column} 
        data={parameters} 
        pagination
        fixedHeader
        fixedHeaderScrollHeight="450px"
        highlightOnHover
        actions={<AddParameter loadParameter = {loadParameter} />}
        
      subHeader

    />
```

Finally, as you said in the comments that you want to clear the text boxes, you just have to call a function when closing the modal.

```
const resetTextAfterClosing = () => {
    setParameter({
        param_name: "",
        param_sequence_number: "",
        param_value: "",
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, that work perfectly, for resetting the state using the function resetTextAfterClosing, question is it okay that I will call this in the submit button onClick in the modal?

Comment: I think it is ok if you call it after making the request. You may also need to call it when click close button too.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, you want to refresh table data after removing of user value. you learn about parent to child, child to parent  concept in react and implement in project then solved your problem.

```
    //example: Parent Component;

    function ParentA(){
       const [state,setstate] = useState(false);
    
       useEffect(() => {
          //call fetch data method;
       },[state]);
    
       return(
          <ChildA state={state} setstate={setstate} />
       )
    }
    
    //child component.

    function ChildA({state, setstate}){
       const renderData = () => {
         setstate(!state);
       }

       return (
          <button onClick={renderData}>Click here</button>
       )
    }
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the reply, but it's the other way around, I just want to refresh the table data after adding new records

Answer (score 0):

In "**onSubmit**" function, **set the axios response** which contains all data in "**setParameters**" and

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadParameters();
}, [parameters]);
```

Hope, this will solve your problem. But have some studies about **props drilling** and **parent-child components**

Comment: This will trigger an infinite loop since loadParameters sets the parameters and you have those in your dependencies.

Comment: not actually!
cause, "parameters" is only changing after saving data when it gets axios response from server.

Comment: It does not matter, you can see an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-leftpad-u0e2fb?file=/src/App.tsx